# Nested for loops in R, termination

Tags: r, loops

Here is some unexpected R behavior.

```
for(i in 1:3)
{
  for(j in (i+1):3)
  {
    print(paste(i,j))
  }
}
```

yields:

```
[1] "1 2"
[1] "1 3"
[1] "2 3"
[1] "3 4"
[1] "3 3"
```

Why does it not stop at "2 3"?

Comment: `5:3` gives the sequence `c(5,4,3)`. See `?":"`, *"For other arguments from:to is equivalent to seq(from, to), and generates a sequence from from to to in steps of 1 or -1."*

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

That is because in the second for for loop you go from 4 to 3 backwards when `i` = 3. *R includes both the lower and the upper number in the sequence* (in contrast to many other languages). Thus, `1:3` will return a vector of `c(1,2,3)` including both 1 and 3.

Check `` ?`:` `` for more information.

Therefore, the loop continues to run. To stop the running loop, you might consider `?break` inside an `if` check, or reconsider the ranges your loops will be applied to.

Comment: Many thanks. "in contrast to many other languages" - exactly :)